# MvvmCross 6.0 Navigate to viewmodel before closing current viewmodel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a simple series of screens where the user sees a list of entries (Screen A), hits a create new entry (Screen B), and a screen to view the newly created entry (Screen C).

After creating a new entry (Screen B) and navigating to it, I want to remove the create screen (Screen B) from the stack. Is there a  simple way in the new navigation service to accomplish this smoothly? It would be nice if I didn't have to create a custom presenter for something so simple.

I've attempted having Screen B navigate to Screen C, and then closing itself, but that reverts to Screen A.

I've attempted having Screen B return a result to Screen A, which then takes the result and navigates to Screen C, but that causes the screen to flash Screen A before the navigation occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies in the Navigation Stack. I believe what you're looking for is the [`RemovePage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.removepage?view=xamarin-forms) method. Here's a bit of information on how to manipulate the [Xamarin.Forms Navigation Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#manipulating-the-navigation-stack). This means that you could potentially call `RemovePage` (for Screen B) once you navigated to the Screen C.

The above refers to how you would approach this in the UI layer. If you want to stay in the ViewModel world, you should look into the `Close` method on the `MvxNavigationService` (which, if I'm not mistaken, calls [`RemoveByViewModel`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross.Forms/Presenters/MvxFormsPagePresenter.cs#L296) in the `MvxFormsPagePresenter`). This solution, unfortunately requires you to have the instance of the ViewModel that you want to Close handy, as you need to pass it as a parameter to the method - how to achieve that is completely up to you.

EDIT:

It might be that (not verified info) the Presenter, when `Close` method is being invoked on the ViewModel, is calling [`PopToViewModel`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross.Forms/Presenters/MvxFormsPagePresenter.cs#L333), which pops all of the views up until the specified ViewModel. The solution could be to create custom presenter and override the `ChangePresentation` method and inject there custom logic. Otherwise, I would suggest just using `RemovePage` method on the `NavigationPage`

Comment: Closing Screen B causes Screen C to also be removed from the stack.

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure about this, but I think that the [`PopToViewModel`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross.Forms/Presenters/MvxFormsPagePresenter.cs#L333) might be invoked and that's why both of these screens are getting closed. The possible solution here would be to create custom presenter and override `ChangePresentation` method and create custom logic to handle your scenario. If you don't want to fiddle with that, I would just call the `RemovePage`

Comment: I was hoping to avoid making a custom presenter, but it looks like that might be what I'll have to do. The application is not using Xamarin Forms, so RemovePage is off the table.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it's forms as you haven't mentioned any specific platform. What platform(s) are you targeting?

Comment: Only Android at this time. I'm familiar with custom presenters, I was just expecting I wouldn't have to do one with their new navigation system.

Comment: Ok, you should ignore my comments on the `PopToView` method being called, as obviously you're not dealing with Forms presenter but with android one ([`MvxAndroidViewPresenter`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Presenters/MvxAndroidViewPresenter.cs)). I don't think you will be able to avoid creating a custom one though - which in the end is not a big deal.